# Android ListView - football table with different cell width

Tags: android, listview

I've done a lot of research but havent't found a solution for my Android ListView problem!

My layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

In this ListView I'd like to display a football table where the coloumns have different width (e.g. team title should be wider than points)! Therefore I created the following row-layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/team_line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_place"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#d08021"
                android:paddingRight="6dip"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_name"
                android:layout_width="140dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_games"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_games_win"
                android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            /> 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_games_draw"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />        
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_games_loose"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />                
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_goals_shot"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_goals_got"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_points"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />                                     
    </LinearLayout>
```

The ListView works in normal mode, but in Landscape mode the full screen size isn't used!
I don't know if my layout_width properties are right. What is the maximal size (in dip) I can use?

I tried to use different layout_width parameters with different layout_width values but haven't got a solution yet.

What is the best way to get the "cells" of my listview aligned properly with different width for normal and landscape mode? Isn't there a possible way of using percentage values?

I hope anyone can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Why don't you use a table layout within a scroll view instead of a listview?

Comment: thanks for your answer! i used it because i need the onlistitemclick!

Comment: You can use onTouchEvent() on the TableRow instead.